# Facebook Graph API inbox messages with no comments array

Tags: json, facebook-graph-api

Some inbox messages in the Graph API have no comments array. Comments are the actual messages in the thread. Are these messages simply not available to API users?

Example:

```
{
    "unread": 0,
    "to": {
        "data": [
            {
                "id": "666397291",
                "name": "Miguel Paraz"
            },
            {
                "id": "xxxxxx",
                "name": "xxxxxx"
            }
        ]
    },
    "id": "56002435955",
    "updated_time": "2013-01-19T06:33:59+0000",
    "unseen": 0
}
```

The comments are there when I open the inbox in the Facebook website or mobile app.

When I attempt to retrieve this thread specifically, I get:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request.",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, and only way, I've found to solve this - use FQL multiquery instead of Graph API. Using this query:

```
    {
    'messages': 'SELECT body,created_time, author_id  FROM message WHERE thread_id IN 
    (SELECT thread_id FROM thread WHERE folder_id = 0) and author_id != me() ORDER BY created_time DESC',
    'names': 'SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT author_id FROM #messages)' 
    }
```

retuns result, like this:

```
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "name": "messages", 
          "fql_result_set": [
            {
              "body": "body of message", 
              "created_time": 1344741084, 
              "author_id": 0
            },...
          ]
        }, 
        {
          "name": "names", 
          "fql_result_set": [
            {
              "uid": "id of user from first query", 
              "name": "user_name"
            },...
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

then i first parse result of second query into hashmap and after this parse result of first query into my data structure, replacing author_id with name from hashmap.

If you need additional info about user or message - just add columns to SELECT statement of queries.

Hope this helps.